# Terraform refresh from empty state?

Tags: terraform

I am developing a custom Terraform provider for our private cloud, and i struggle with the state file between my builds.

Basically every time i build a new version of the custom provider, i need to perform a `terraform init`, which seems to wipe out the existing state.

I have some resources that still exist, but Terraform thinks they don't, since its state file is empty.

I tried to perform a `terraform refresh`, but it doesn't do anything:

> Empty or non-existent state file.
>
> Refresh will do nothing. Refresh does not error or return an erroneous
>   exit status because many automation scripts use refresh, plan, then
>   apply and may not have a state file yet for the first run.

I saw in the documentation that one can `import` existing infrastructure, but for this the provider needs to implement the import function.

**Is there a way to force Terraform to refresh the state?**

Comment: `terraform init` definitely shouldn't wipe out the state. Are you sure you're writing state out properly in the first place?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i may have assumed that `terraform init` wipes the state. The state is written fine. I am also updating resources outside of terraform to perform some tests etc, so at some point i may have an out-of-sync state. But maybe `import` is the only way to refresh the state for resources that are not yet in the state, but are in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i needed to implement the `import` function for my provider, as `terraform refresh` can't refresh resources that are not in the `State`.